# How can I read, edit an old array and save the new array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, text-files, coordinates, jsfiddle

I have a small problem please help me. I have a simple script in JSFiddle. More specifically, first of all I have a text file with coordinates and an id for each pair of coordinates. This text file is shown here:

```
{
"displayFieldName": "",
"fieldAliases": {
    "FID": "FID",
    "Id": "Id",
    "Longtitude": "Longtitude",
    "Latitude": "Latitude"
},
"geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
"spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 4326,
    "latestWkid": 4326
},
"fields": [{
    "name": "FID",
    "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
    "alias": "FID"
}, {
    "name": "Id",
    "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
    "alias": "Id"
}, {
    "name": "Longtitude",
    "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
    "alias": "Longtitude"
}, {
    "name": "Latitude",
    "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
    "alias": "Latitude"
}],
"features": [{
    "attributes": {
        "FID": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "Longtitude": 23.739000000000001,
        "Latitude": 37.972000000000001
    },
    "geometry": {
        "x": 23.739000000000001,
        "y": 37.972000000000001
    }
}, {
    "attributes": {
        "FID": 1,
        "Id": 2,
        "Longtitude": 23.760100000000001,
        "Latitude": 37.984999999999999
    },
    "geometry": {
        "x": 23.760100000000001,
        "y": 37.984999999999999
    }
}, {
    "attributes": {
        "FID": 2,
        "Id": 3,
        "Longtitude": 23.749199999999998,
        "Latitude": 37.975999999999999
    },
    "geometry": {
        "x": 23.749199999999998,
        "y": 37.975999999999999
    }
}, {
    "attributes": {
        "FID": 3,
        "Id": 4,
        "Longtitude": 23.735700000000001,
        "Latitude": 37.975999999999999
    },
    "geometry": {
        "x": 23.735700000000001,
        "y": 37.975999999999999
    }
}]
}
```

This text file is read by a small script (in JSFiddle) and after all, is saved in an array "text":

```
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<img id='output'>
<script>
var openFile = function(event) {
var input = event.target;

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
  var text = reader.result;
  console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
  console.log(text);
};
reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};

</script>
```

My question is: I want for every pair of coordinates to add a new column, `z`. This column will be computed like this: `z=Longtitude+Latitude` (`long`, `lat` are variables that exist in text). So basically, I want a repeat in the array "text", where I can compute a new column and also keep the old ones (longitude, latitude and Id columns). In my mind, I want these 4 columns to be exported to a new text file. I hope you understand what I am saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the array then..

```
text["features"].forEach(function(feature){
    feature["geometry"].z = feature["attributes"].Longtitude + 
    feature["attributes"].Latitude;
})
```

here, `forEach` iterates over all the elements in the array(in your case text["features"] is an array of objects). function is passed as an parameter to forEach.[forEach docs MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

if you want an copy of array use `map` on text.

```
let newArray = text["features"].map(function(feature){
    return feature["attributes"].Longtitude + feature["attributes"].Latitude;
})
```

`map` iterates over the array and gives an updated new array.[map docs MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPPnY.png).

hope that's helpful!

Comment: hello @Parth Shah! Thanks for your reply! I tried this in my code in JSFIDDLE but it doesn't work.. :( I Put your code after my code inside the script..

Comment: @IriniK. how about you share your JSFiddle.

Comment: OK, the txt file (i dont know how to give to you) is the one you see in the begining of this query! Thank you so much for helping me! https://jsfiddle.net/irinikonsta/n5jazrwq/

Comment: Hey gotit! :D
When u read the txt file, it is taken as `String`. So, `typeof text` will show String . You need to convert string to Object here. For that you could use `JSON.parse` and to reverse that effect use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/taksuparth/1bszprfr/2/ in the text object you can find it under feature object's geometry object's z property.

Comment: i didn't understand i am sorry! @Parth Shah

Comment: this jsfiddle you gave me, it's the right one? i mean there do you convert string to object? and then the repeat and the new array are becoming there?

Comment: yes, it's the right one! you can see z-property added in attached snapshot in answer

Answer (score 0):

try this demo;

https://jsfiddle.net/n5jazrwq/4/

upload the txt and you will see save link,click it and you will download the target data.txt

transform data by this:

```
  features.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    obj.geometry.z = obj.attributes.Latitude + obj.attributes.Longtitude;
  });
```

download data function is this:

```
exportData(JSON.stringify(data));
```